# Can we add a [bedops] tag?

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering how tags are added. I'm a new user to this SE site, so I don't have the reputation to add new tags. Can we please add a `bedops` tag to make it easier to find, ask, and answer questions about this toolkit?

Comment: would definitely have `bedops` as one of the tag owing to its usage and popularity. I would definitely support it.

Comment: Yes, when people start to ask questions about bedops.

Answer (score 6):

This early in the beta, there's a lot of flexibility in creating new tags. Users, even new ones, are unrestricted in which tags they can use, so tags are being created pretty quickly right now. There's some effort going into tag quality control right now, which is documented in some of the other questions in the meta.

Questions about bedops usage are definitely on topic here, and the `bedops` tag is definitely appropriate. That said, there's no way to create the tag until someone actually asks a question about bedops and tags it accordingly.

You're certainly welcome to seed the topic here with a couple of questions. Be careful though, the StackExchange community is wary about any content that feels too much like advertising. But done tactfully, using Bioinformatics.SE as a support forum for bedops should be fine. See relevant discussion [here](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/96).